# Python Pandas DataFrame column calls by column index but not name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So here I import a csv file into python and then try to do something with the first column: 'Type', but I keep getting the message:

"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Type' ".

Printing the column by name does not work, but printing it by location does. Why does referencing it by name not work? It works for all other columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('ResturantData.csv', sep=',', index_col=False) 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

print(df.head())
print(df.columns)

print(df.iloc[:, 0])    #Works! 
print(df.Type)          #Doesn't work :/
print(df['Type'])       #Doesn't work :/
```

Here is what the DataFrame looks like;

```
     ﻿Type  Size  Bill  Tip
0  Dinner     5   126   12
1  Dinner     4   103   12
2  Dinner     4    94   11
3  Breakfast  4    87   10
4  Dinner     4    76    7
```

Thanks!

Comment: You probably have extra whitespace. What is the output of `df.columns.tolist()`

Comment: As @ayhan point out, maybe try `df[' Type']`

Comment: @Wen Yes as an alternative `skipinitialspace=True` can be passed to read_csv.

Answer (score 0):

The first character of your `Type` column isn't ascii.  It's `'\ufeff'`.

Here's a way to strip non-ascii from your column names.

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: ''.join([y for y in x if ord(y) < 128]), inplace=True)

df.Type

0       Dinner
1       Dinner
2       Dinner
3    Breakfast
4       Dinner
Name: Type, dtype: object
```

Comment: This was it, thank you!! How do I make it ascii in the original csv?